# Gaussian Mixture Model with Custom Distance Metric

Tags: machine-learning, python, distance-functions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, metric

I have some 1D data that I want to cluster using Mixture of Gaussian. However, the data "wraps around" at two extremes. Specifically, I have a list of angles from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and the data near two ends should actually be close to each other. Thus, if I just use GMM naively I will get very poor result. So is there a way to make the learning algorithm aware of this kind of distance metric? Any theory or practical methods are appreciated. I am using `Python's scikit-learn` so it would be great if it supports it natively. However, I did not find such feature. Last, if anyone know of any general method to deal with any distance metric between high-dimensional data points, some references are also great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you cluster 1D data "by hand"?

Comment: In case of a general dimension, take a look at [von Mises distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution). There are papers on von Mises Clustering, like [this one](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/gopal14.pdf). Unfortunately, I don't know if any of them are implemented in any software toolkits.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe What do you mean "by hand"? I am writing a program in which clustering is part of it.